# Python cv2.imshow() not working: cannot connect to X server

Tags: python, docker, opencv, terminal, centos

situation: Running a CentOS terminal in a docker container on a windows host. cv2 installed, working perfectly.
script:

```
import sys
import cv2
def main(argv):
        inputfile = ''
        for arg in argv:
                img = cv2.imread(arg)
                cv2.imshow('Image', img)
                cv2.waitkey(0)
if __name__ == "__main__":
        main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Error: `: cannot connect to X server`
Tried solution:
`[root@b26030f33e65 PythonScripts]# xhost local:root
xhost:  unable to open display ""`

Comment: There's most likely no X installed in your dockerized CentOS because it won't render things on a screen.

Comment: and how can I check if X is installed/ install if not installed

Comment: You'd need to mount your host's X server to the docker container as that's the one handling your on-screen GUI applications. Maybe this can help: https://medium.com/@SaravSun/running-gui-applications-inside-docker-containers-83d65c0db110

Comment: Looks like the solution I need, but that's for linux systems. My host system is windows. Is there any other documentation on that?

Comment: Windows does not provide an X server, there are just client applications to my knowledge. Wouldn't writing the image to a file on a mounted volume be a solution? You can then easily access/open it on the host system and don't need a window from the container's system.

Comment: That could be a good solution, but my goal was to create a tool for my terminal so i could view images.

Answer (score 1):

For windows you could try one of the various Xserver implementations, the most simple one being [VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/files/vcxsrv/), other implementations are available from the Cygwin world and there are also some comercial solutions.

The main idea would be to start the Xserver making it to listen on TCP on all interfaces and without any auth then connect to it from the container over TCP

```
inside_container > export DISPLAY="<some ip>:0"
inside_container > # start your whatever
```

Note: listening on all interfaces and without auth is not the safe, you should use it only in the initial fase until you get the things running, afterwards you should take the necessary step to reduce the "exposed surface".

Now ... I'm not really sure how exactly to make you IP visible to the container, but I hope that this could be enough to get you started.

**Later Edit:**
I've found [this](https://dev.to/darksmile92/run-gui-app-in-linux-docker-container-on-windows-host-4kde) (over-complicated) step-by-step guide, which basically says pretty much the same thing:

- install VcXsrv (or Xming, or whatever)
- start it with :

  - "Multiple windows" for a more streamlined experience
  - "no client"
  - "Disable access control" (again only to avoid the initial hassle)
- whenever you need to run some GUI app, add a `DISPLAY` env var pointing to your "display"

```
# example
> docker run -ti --rm -e DISPLAY=172.17.0.1:0.0 firefox
> docker run -ti --rm -e DISPLAY=172.17.0.1:0.0 /bin/sh
# where "172.17.0.1" would be 1 of your IPs
```

Comment: This is a nice solution to my problem, but I wanted to create a tool for my terminal to use it there. I will definitly look to this solution. I've only got 2 questions: can i still pass the DISPLAY env var when my container has already been created? and the ip passed into it, is it the internat ip of my host computer?

Comment: Just use localhost and start your container with `—net=host`

Comment: The DISPLAY env var definition must be prior to launching the tool tool/program/script (or even a python shell) that's about to open some "GUI window" , ... I'm not sure if you can somehow "inject" env vars to a running program. But if you are connecting to a running container and you are about to start a new tool/program/script/... you can define the env var and then start it.

Answer (score 0):

On unix-like systems, you can pass-through the host's X server (if any) to the docker container by setting up a set of required mounts (see [this article for an idea](https://medium.com/@SaravSun/running-gui-applications-inside-docker-containers-83d65c0db110)).

Since you are on Windows, there's hardly any chance that you can pass-through X from your host to your container since Windows does not run an X server; it uses other systems for on-screen rendering.

I think the only possible solution for you is to mount a directory from your host to your container and write your image to a file in that directory. It's then easily accessible from your host system.

Just run your container with arguments similar to:

```
docker run
  --rm -ti
  --volume /path/to/host/directory:/path/to/container/directory:rw
  --entrypoint=/bin/bash
  yourcentosimagename
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, but my goal was to create a tool/script so I could view my image files in my terminal directly. I've already got a mounted volume so i can always check the image by copying it to my host system.